# Homebrew: Could not create link for , as it conflicts with Homebrew/homebrew/libarchive

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

Full Error:

```
Warning: Could not create link for , as it
conflicts with Homebrew/homebrew/libarchive. You will need to use the
fully-qualified name when referring this formula, e.g.
  brew install
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Strange how it is just and `,` ? Not sure how to resolve. I have run:

1. `brew prune`
2. `cd $(brew --prefix)`
3. `git reset --hard HEAD`
4. `git clean -df`

Then re-run, with the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: What command did you run that gives you this error?

Comment: `pip install` or `pip install <anything_here>`

Comment: Oof - sorry, having two issues at once. I meant `brew update`